# Uncharged grounded conducting sphere in a uniform electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

When we place an uncharged grounded conducting sphere in a uniform electric field, then due to the external field, charges will be induced on its surface. But if the sphere is grounded, then why won't the charges get neutralised?